# How to handle dependency between two unrelated objects?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript

I am trying to figure out a way to solve the following dependency problem.

I have a parent object `DomManager` that has the responsibility to handle all the interaction with the DOM. It initializes several modules and two of them are dependent of each other: `PlayerDom` and `Sticky`.

At a certain point, a `PlayerDom`'s method needs to call a method of `Sticky` (and vice versa).

After several iterations, I came up with the following implementation:

**DomManager**

```
var DomManager = {
// General configuration
config: null,

// Modules container
modules: {},

/**
 * Initialization function
 *
 * @param config - Configuration object
 * @returns {DomManager} - DomManager object
 */
init: function(config) {
    this.config = this.setConfig(config);

    this.initModules();

    return this;
},

setConfig: function(config) {
    return config;
},

/**
 * Invoke a service from a particular module
 *
 * @param moduleName - Module name
 * @param service - Method name to be invoked
 * @param args - Optional method parameters
 */
invoke: function(moduleName, service, args) {
    if (this.modules[moduleName] && typeof this.module[moduleName][service] === 'function') {
        this.modules[moduleName][service](args);
    }
},

/**
 * Initializes all modules it depends on
 */
initModules: function() {
    // Initialize player DOM manager
    this.modules['playerDom'] = PlayerDom.init(this.config.playerDom);

    // Stickiness is NOT enabled on videogallery
    if (this.config.sticky.enabled) {
        this.modules['sticky'] = Sticky.init(this.config.sticky);
    }

    // Top leaderboard stickiness is enabled only on mobile
    if (this.config.topLeaderBoard.enabled) {
        this.modules['topleaderboard'] = TopLeaderBoard.init(this.config.topLeaderBoard);
    }

    // Read more is enabled only if the following conditions are met:
    // - Template A
    // - One of: Facebook Referrer, Mobile, Tablet
    if (this.config.readMore.enabled) {
        this.modules['readMore'] = ReadMore.init(this.config.readMore);
    }
}
```

};

So when `PlayerDom` needs to call a service of `Sticky`, it needs to call, for example, `DomManager.invoke('sticky', 'enable')`.

Could it be a good solution or is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand DomManager in your implementation is a DI manager as well. If it creates modules upon initialization, then it probably make sense to add a method like DomManager.get(moduleName) or DomManager.inject(moduleName) and use it in the child modules like so:

```
let sticky = DomManager.get(Sticky);
sticky.doSomething();
```

Such approach is used in Angular, when there are services dependent on each other: https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js